# Using <p:fileUpload > with the <h:inputText> doesn't get the inputext mapping value while uploading

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces `<p:fileUpload >` with `<h:inputText>` inside. The problem which i am facing is when i upload image and add the title for the image, the images are uploaded but the inputText values will contains null,doesn't mapping to the bean.

Jsf Page for Image Upload:

```
     <p:fileUpload id="imaload" fileUploadListener="#{ngoPhotoUpload.photoUpload}"  
                         mode="advanced"  multiple="true" 
                          update="messages" 
                           allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/">
     <h:inputText value="#{ngoPhotoBean.description}"/>
     </p:fileUpload>
```

When i upload the ngoPhotoBean.description contains null. I am using primefaces 3.0 and jsf 2.0. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that primefaces p:remotecommand tag is there.. You can pass the argument using that tag.This link can help you..

[how to pass the parameter during file upload in primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909492/how-to-pass-the-parameter-during-file-upload-in-primefaces)

Comment: Hi Sathesh , It will be great , if u could expalin ur approachwith an example . I mean a code

Answer (score 8):

Use the [fileUpload](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.2/p/fileUpload.html)'s **process** attribute, and push the FileUploadEvent to the INVOKE_APPLICATION phase to see the inputText value in `#{ngoPhotoBean.description}`:

Xhtml:

```
<h:form>
    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{ngoPhotoUpload.photoUpload}" process="@form" update="@form" />
    <h:inputText value="#{ngoPhotoBean.description}" />
</h:form>
```

Java:

```
public void photoUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    if (!PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION.equals(event.getPhaseId())) {
        event.setPhaseId(PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION);
        event.queue();
    } else {
        //do stuff here, #{ngoPhotoBean.description} is set
    }
}
```

Comment: There is one issue using this method..When i upload multiple images at a time only one images have been stored.how to solve it.

Comment: Hi , I used this solution , it worked fine for me. But since im very new to PF , so it will be very helpful for me if u could expalin  if  block logic in detail.

Comment: Although I realize that this is an old thread, just thought that I would clarify that under normal circumstances, the file upload listener is executed during "Apply Request Values". However, anything you specify in the process attribute isn't going to be available until "Update Model Values". So, by setting the event's phase to INVOKE_APPLICATION, you are deferring execution until after that phase has completed and your values are available.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to solve it.
just put <p:ajax /> between <p:textinput> and </p:textinput>